Long initial load of page with Playwright
We are in a situation where we have a large enterprise project. Our team is creating a small part of this project. We are using playwright, which works nicely.
Our issue: For each test, we are using a beforeEach hook to go to the URL of our page. The load time for this can be something like 4-5 seconds due to the project's large scale.
When running playwright on our CI with workers=1, it can take quite a long time to complete the tests as 50% of the time in a test might just be the initial page load time.
So, are there any tricks to be used here? I know the obvious "increase page load performance" but since this is a large enterprise solution that's easier said than done.
I'm looking for some solution to "skip" the page load, maybe save the page in some kind of cache or state. I don't know what's possible.
Let me know if you have any tricks that could help us out. Thanks.
I have tried to create a storageState (normally used for skipping authentication) but that only stores cookies etc, which will not help in this case.

I don't think there's any way to answer this without having a good amount of details and preferably a [mcve]. Have you profiled the code to figure out what's using up all the time? Start optimizing there. If you're not sure where to optimize or profile, keep ripping functionality out of the code (maybe start with that beforeEach hook) and figure out where the bottlenecks are. If your tests don't need the whole page to load, consider blocking resources like images that may not be relevant to the particular test. Hopefully you're using page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "commit"}).
